# convertting equation to matlab /octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have an equation I tried converting to matlab/octave but keep getting a mapping function error.  Can some tell me what I'm doing wrong.  The equation is below.

Thanks

[image]

The matlab/octave code below is

```
fs=44100; %sampling frequency
t=(0:10*fs)/fs; %Time vector
alpha=1.1513;
siga1=cosh*(400*pi*j*(cosh*(alpha*t)-sinh*(alpha*t))/alpha);
siga2=sinh*(400*pi*j*(cosh*(alpha*t)-sinh*(alpha*t))/alpha);
sigb=siga1-siga2;
```

Comment: after cosh and sinh you do not need the *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hyperbolic sine and cosine are functions and you are treating them as variables.

This should work (as long as you have j defined somewhere)

```
fs=44100; %sampling frequency
t=(0:10*fs)/fs; %Time vector
alpha=1.1513;
siga1=cosh(400*pi*j*(cosh(alpha*t)-sinh(alpha*t))/alpha);
siga2=sinh(400*pi*j*(cosh(alpha*t)-sinh(alpha*t))/alpha);
sigb=siga1-siga2;
```

Comment: `j` is a valid alternative to the imaginary unit `i` in Matlab (octave too, I imagine). So actually it will work as long as `j` is *not* defined as something else in the scope of this code. Generally, `1i` and `1j` are preferred though.